# How to elegantly add and remove elements from DOM

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I have a dynamic form where certain inputs should only become available (and visible) based upon what a user has already entered. The way I'm starting to go about it has a wrong smell.

It is straightforward enough to add material to the DOM

```
<script>
function addStuffToTheDOM(s1, s2){
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    s2.innerHTML = "";

    if (s1.value==="job_1"){ 


    s2.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p><select name=&#34;scholarship&#34; id=&#34;scholarship&#34;><option value=&#34;&#34; disabled=&#34;disabled&#34; selected=&#34;selected&#34;>*Position</option> <option value=&#34;&#34; disabled=&#34;disabled&#34; > </option> <option value=&#34;HR&#34;>HR</option> <option value=&#34;CTO&#34;>CTO</option> <option value=&#34;test&#34;>test</option> <option value=&#34;test2&#34;>test2</option> <option value=&#34;test3&#34;>test3</option> <option value=&#34;test4&#34;>test4</option> </select> </p> <select name=&#34;previous_experience&#34; class=&#34;hidden&#34; 
id=&#34;new_to_demo&#34;><option value=&#34;0&#34; disabled=&#34;disabled&#34; selected=&#34;selected&#34;></option> <p> <p> <input type=&#34;text&#34; name=&#34;supervisor&#34; id=&#34;supervisor&#34; maxlength=&#34;50&#34; size=&#34;30&#34;> <label for=&#34;supervisor&#34;>*Supervisor</label> </p> <p> <input type=&#34;text&#34; name=&#34;office_location&#34; id=&#34;office_location&#34; maxlength=&#34;50&#34; size=&#34;30&#34;> <label for=&#34;office_location&#34;>Office location</label> </p> <p> <input type=&#34;text&#34; name=&#34;programme_start_date&#34; id=&#34;programme_start_date&#34; maxlength=&#34;50&#34; size=&#34;30&#34;> <label for=&#34;programme_start_date&#34;>programme_start_date</label> </p>');
    }
}
</script> 

<!-- .... -->

<form>
<!-- ... -->

<select name="type" id="type" onchange="addStuffToTheDOM(this.id, 'alma_mater')">
                    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">*Job Interest?</option>
                    <option value="" disabled="disabled" >                  </option>
                    <option value="job_1">The really big job</option>
                    <option value="job_2">The other job</option>

                </select>
```

And while this insertion in itself could be better (instead of jamming an enormous string into insertAdjacentHTML() ) an immediate problem presents itself in that

1. If the user has made a mistake and selects the other option (for which all that inserted HTML is irrelevant) then some other code will have to be run to remove all those new elements. Yuck.
2. Without this removal process if the user selects the other option and then goes back and selects option "job_1" again, then the form is immediately broken by the duplication of all that content. Yikes.
3. The backend checking has to be extra careful to do proper checking: are inputs empty because they haven't been filled in, or because they simply don't exist?

What would be the ideal methodology for implementing this dynamic content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that has a worrying smell. You could create a check-function that runs each time someone clicks/types (depending on what you want to include in your form) a field. That functions itself needs certain conditions that are going to be checked.

This is  a quick example I put together. Use jQuery (or regular javascript if you want) and put together something like this. Hope this helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#checkbox').click(function(){
    if($("#checkbox").is(':checked'))
      $("#textbox").hide(); 
    else
      $("#textbox").show();  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">I want to hide a textbox</input><br>
  <input id="textbox" type="textbox" placeholder="This can be hidden"></input>
</form>
```

EDIT: To add, if you want to check for textbox values or textareas, in jQuery you use for example:

```
$('#textbox').val();
```

Comment: Yes I think this, along with a cycle of .removeAttribute("required") / createAttribute("required") for the sake of validation is probably the cleanest method of implementation.